# Working with Graph API 1.0 on the new iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

The new Facebook SDK for iOS supports by default the new Graph API 2.0 . Has someone found a way to use the latest Facebook SDK for iOS and run queries of Graph API 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly discourage you to use old version API's. But it is still possible to do what you wish and this means for any API that exists. In one case I found out that Facebook SDK has a couple of features missing from it, which are still supported by the Graph REST API. Even though that Facebook has an abstraction layer that allows for creation of different requests, I went on using AFNetworking. I extracted the user token from Facebook SDK and made custom Graph API calls using AFNetworking 2.0 wrappers.

You can call Graph API 1.0 the same way (or even using `NSURLRequest`), but you could run into other problems, since Facebook has a very sophisticated permissions system and might not allow you to call Graph API 1.0 with wrong user token.

Comment: I agree that it is considered a bad practice to use an old API, but due to many regressions in the functionality in API 2.0, I would need to continue to use the old API up until they would not support it. 

Thanks for the suggestion, but I wasn't able to make it work that way, because the begin session method uses API 2.0

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to use v1.0 of the Graph API, and that is by using an App **created before v2.0 was introduced (end of April 2014)**. You can not use v1.0 with an App created after that date.

...and that oppertunity will be gone after end of April 2015, when v1.0 will be completely gone

In theory you should be able to use any SDK with any API version btw. In the end it is just an astraction layer.

Comment: Thanks, that is how I am using it for now, but my question was if I can use the API 1.0 with the latest Facebook SDK?

Comment: i will add some information about that in the question

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. That is what I meant when I said: "Has someone found a way to use the latest Facebook SDK for iOS and run queries of Graph API 1.0"